# How to set php datetime with current time in an if and else statement

Tags: php

I am fetching a future date time from my database and i want it to change it status to something else as soon as it matches up with current datetime

What i want is my display to change as soon as the future time matches up with current time but it is not working right.

```
<?php $timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s", time()); ?>

$sql  = "SELECT * FROM games Where types='Games' ";
$sql .= "ORDER by id DESC ";
$games = Game::find_by_sql($sql);

<thead>
<tr class="btn-success">
    <th>Kick Off</th>
</tr>   
</thead>
<tbody>

<?php foreach($games as $game): ?>
<tr>
<td>
    <?php
    if($game->kick_off > $timestamp){
        ?>
        <span class="fas fa-clock-o fa-spin"></span><?php echo $game->kick_off; ?>
    <?php   
    }else{
        if($game->kick_off < $timestamp){
        ?>
        <span class="fas fa-futbol fa-spin"></span>
    <?php
    }
    }
    ?>
    </td>
    </tbody>
```

Comment: What datatype is the `kick_off` column in your database

Comment: If kick_off is Not > timestamp then it is less than or equal too it. So the second IF seems a bit like unnecessary complexity

Comment: "Not working right". What _are_ you seeing, and what were you _expecting_ to see? Are you expecting the icon to change without refreshing the page or something?

Comment: If you want a "real time" changement in your page, you need to use some ajax + setInterval for example or it will work only if you reload your page and kick-off become < timestamp

Comment: @RiggsFolly datatype is also datetime from the database. Do you mean i should change > sign to less than sign < ?

Comment: @MickaëlLeger it works if i change to less than sign yes!

Comment: @jonnix i am expecting  to change after refreshing ofcourse.

Comment: @MickaëlLeger any ideas on how to use ajax for that??? i mean link?

Comment: You have your page. In this page, you do a JS function that will do an Ajax call to a PHP each X seconds. In this PHP, you will just return the "kick_off" value so in your Ajax call, in the success part you get this "kick_off" value, you compare it to the current date-time and you change your HTML using JS. This way, each X second the content will be reload in your page so if kick_off become < now it will change without reloading the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `strftime("%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s", time())` parameters you have used are wrong, and you dont need the `time()` as that is the default.

these are what I believe you should have used

```
$timestamp = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S");
```

RESULT, this produces a string like this

```
2019-06-26 13:53:59
```

It might have been easier to use a simple

```
$timestamp = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

RESULT the same as above

```
2019-06-26 13:53:59
```

This would also be a simpler piece of PHP

```
if($game->kick_off > $timestamp){
    // Game not started
    echo '<span class="fas fa-clock-o fa-spin">' . $game->kick_off . '</span>';
    // I also put the kickoff time INSIDE the span, I assume this was a typo
}else{
    // Game has started
    echo '<span class="fas fa-clock-o fa-spin"></span>';
}
```

Comment: code is performing the else function... Is there anyother method you suggest? my insert statement, inserts a match for future date and time...

Comment: Question: Do you need the time NOW to have any relevance to locale?

Comment: code is working fine thanks... i made a mistake with the 12hour clock and 24hour clock that was the reason it kept displaying the else function...